# lower bound of convergent infinite products

Tags: calculus, infinite-product

If an infinite product
\[
\prod_{n} (1 + a_{n}(s))
\]
converges, then can we say anything about its lower bound?

Or in general, can it take any value arbitrarily close to $0$?

What if $a_{n}$ is of the form $a_{n}(s) = b_{n}m_{n}^{-s}$, where $\{m_{n} \}$ is a subsequence of $\{1, 2, \ldots \}$ and |b_{n}| = 1?

Comment: I get the impression that you probably have conditions on the $a_n(s)$ in mind that you didn't state. As written, the $1+$ is irrelevant; you could just as well shift the $a_n(s)$ and write $\prod_na_n(s)$, and you could trivially make the product come out as any desired value simply by changing the first factor accordingly.

Comment: Then only condition is $a_{n}(s) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: That's not an additional condition; that follows from the convergence of the product, which is already a condition in the question.

Comment: Okay. What if $a_{n}(s)$ is of the form $c_{n}m_{n}^{-s}$ where $|c_{n}| = 1$ and $m_{n}$ is a subsequence of all naturals?

Comment: The naturals aren't a sequence, so they don't have subsequences.

Comment: I mean, $\{m_{n} \} \subset \mathbb{N}$. By the way, your answer is unsatisfactory.

Comment: Why is it unsatisfactory?

Comment: Your "What if" is a whole new question. I suggest you post it as a new question.

Comment: I edited the question. Hope you might give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

The product can take an arbitrary value, in particular any value arbitrarily close to zero. Take any infinite product that converges to some value $\alpha$. To let it converge to arbitrary $\beta\in\mathbb C$ instead, multiply the first factor by $\beta/\alpha$. In terms of your factors $1+a_n(s)$, you need

$$
1+a_n'(s)=\frac\beta\alpha(1+a_n(s))
$$

and thus

$$
a_n'(s)=\frac\beta\alpha(1+a_n(s))-1\;.
$$

*Edit in response to the new question*:

The product can still be zero if $b_1=-1$ and $m_1=1$. Excluding this trivial case, whether the product can converge to zero now depends on $s$.

Since the product converges, $a_n$ converges to $0$; it follows that $s\gt0$. Then the product is minimal if $b_n=-1$ and $m_n=n$ for all $n\ge2$, yielding

$$
\prod_{n\ge2}\left(1-n^{-s}\right)\;,
$$

with another factor of $2$ if we choose to include $m_1=1$ with $b_1=1$. We can obtain a lower bound as follows:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\prod_{n\ge2}\left(1-n^{-s}\right)
&=&
\exp\left(\sum_{n\ge2}\log\left(1-n^{-s}\right)\right)\\
&\lt&
\exp\left(-\sum_{n\ge2}n^{-s}\right)\\
&=&\exp\left(1-\zeta(s)\right)\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

This holds for $s\gt1$. The zeta function has a pole at $s=1$, and in this case the sum in the exponent diverges logarithmically as $n\to\infty$. Thus, for $s\le1$ the product can converge to zero.